# PHP - GetSQLValueString - Para que serve esta função, gerada pelo Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, mysql

Para que serve `GetSQLValueString`? E se há uma diferença para o PHP7, que diferença essa função faz? O que acontece se eu não usar? Alguém pode me ajudar a entender isso melhor?

```
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) 
{
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
        if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        }

        $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
            break;    
            case "long":
            case "int":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
            break;
            case "double":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
            break;
            case "date":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
            break;
            case "defined":
            $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
            break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
}
```

**Depois disso, há uma seção que usa essa função.**

```
if($cod_u > 0){
    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE usuario SET cod_id=%s, nome=%s, sexo=%s   WHERE cod_u=%s",
     GetSQLValueString( utf8_decode($_POST['cod_id']), "int"),
```

Comment: leia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458180/php-getsqlvaluestring-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei o motivo do Dreameaver criar esta função (não o utilizo), mas ela faz o seguinte:

Recebe um valor (`$theValue`) e passa pela função `mysql_real_escape_string`, que faz algumas verificações e mudanças no texto da variável para tornar impossível ataques de [SQL Injection](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-injection/6102).

Em seguida verifica qual tipo de dado você está tentando inserir no banco transforma o texto para o formato válido para executar uma query no banco.

Por exemplo, se o `$theType` for `"text"` ela pega o valor e concatena aspas simples antes e depois do texto, se for `"int"` ela utiliza a função `intval` para passar apenas o valor numérico, etc.
Caso não haja nada na variável `$theValue` ela a transforma em `NULL` para inserir o campo vazio no banco.

O Dreamweaver parece estar utilizando o cliente [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php), <strike>que é uma forma bem antiga de se conectar ao banco de dados</strike>. O padrão mais moderno e recomendado é a utilização do [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php), que é orientado a objeto e possui maior segurança.

Respondendo a pergunta `E o que acontece se eu não usar?`:
Se você recebe o valor diretamente do browser e não utiliza uma função de escape dos caracteres fica vulnerável a ataques. Veja a documentação do [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Edit:
Correção: O `mysqli` é seguro e rápido (mais rápido do que o `PDO` em certos casos), na verdade é o [mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php) que está depreciado.